# PHPMyadmin redirection issues on Apache2

Tags: debian, apache2, redirection, phpmyadmin

A couple of days back I updated Apache on the webserver. Which seems to have broken accessing Phpmyadmin through server IP:

```
server.ip/phpmyadmin
```

Instead now when typing above the ip/phpmyadmin it redirects to the domain which is hosted on the server.

```
domain.com/phpmyadmin
```

It gives a 404 error obviously, since /var/html/www where the domain is pointed has no Phpmyadmin directory/resource.

I have tried the following, upto no avail:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin
```

Checked the following directories for any reference to phpmyadmin redirection:

```
/etc/apache2
/etc/phpmyadmin
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Check your `/etc/apache2/[sites- | conf-][enabled | available]/` directories and maybe `/etc/apache2/conf.d/`. Sounds like your upgrade killed the default page and uses the default vhosts.

Answer (score 0):

PHPMyadmin was set to use SSL.

Using 'https' instead of 'http' resolved the issue.